# Extract image from a sample json response in android

Tags: android, json, image

How do I extract the image from this JSON response and display it in a list view?

The image url is in the fields object:

```
"results":[  
  {  
    "id":"world/2017/sep/24/german-election-merkel-polls-open-amid-fears-over-far-right-afd-surge",
    "type":"article",
    "sectionId":"world",
    "sectionName":"World news",
    "webPublicationDate":"2017-09-24T06:44:14Z",
    "webTitle":"German election: polls open amid fears over surge of far-right AfD",
    "webUrl":"https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/sep/24/german-election-merkel-polls-open-amid-fears-over-far-right-afd-surge",
    "fields":{
        "thumbnail":"https://media.guim.co.uk/971aa3d5064bcf656de9d6c775c1012752426821/0_18_3500_2100/500.jpg"
    },
    "isHosted":false
  }
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with and what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Parsing the JSON

Comment: I am parsing this json response and i want to extract the thumbnail

Comment: Use a photo loading library such as Glide

Comment: Edited for format and clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to get "fields" object first. And in "fields" object get the property "thumbnail" and download the image. Or you can use any library like Glide or picasso for that purpose.

Below are the links to use glide and picasso.

Glide:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/code-an-image-gallery-android-app-with-glide--cms-28207

Picasso:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149

Comment: How can i use glide or picasso library ??

Comment: Happy to see you happy :) happy coding

Comment: I need some more help from you

Comment: Post the question what you need :)

Comment: I am working on a news app and I get the date and time from the json response in this pattern (2017-09-23T14:22:28Z).

How can I convert this date and time into something like that (5 seconds ago, 10 minutes ago, 3 hours ago, etc)? And after 24 hours past, it should then display the normal date of that particular news headline (2017-09-23).

Comment: I cannot see your question.Please paste the link of that question here

Comment: That question has already many answers available. That did not work for you?

Comment: No, those answers didn't help me that much

Comment: I am still confuse